# How can understand the *(void **)(&m_handle) = dlsym("./haldle_lib.so", "custom_func");

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, dlsym

Just want to understand the following code:

Why we use option (1) other than option (2)? I don't know what's the use of (void**) here? really confused.

```
Class Handle{
    private:
    int unique_id;
    int (*m_handle)(int arg1, int arg2);
    public:
    bool init(){
        *(void **)(&m_handle) = dlsym(dlopen(./haldle_lib.so, RTLD_NOW), "custom_func"); // (1)
        //m_handle = (decltype(m_handle))dlsym(dlopen(./haldle_lib.so, RTLD_NOW), "custom_func");//(2)
    }
}
```

add reference https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/C++-dlopen.pdf

Comment: `dlopen(./haldle_lib.so, RTLD_NOW)` is a syntax error, the `.` operator must have a left operand. Please check this is the actual code

Comment: @M.M: Looks like missing quotes. But I agree, not real code.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a pointer of type `void*` to a function pointer is not allowed. In other words, from C++ point of view, function pointers and object pointers are not the same thing.

In option 1, the trick is that you first get the address of the function pointer (`&m_handle`). Then you pretend that this pointer (i.e. `&m_handle`) points to an ordinary object pointer (of type void*) and not to a pointer to a function pointer. Using this pointer (`(void **)(&m_handle)`), you use `operator*` to deference it and and write the value returned by `dlsym(..)` into the function pointer.

Comment: thanks, it's really helpful to understand the trick. BTW, is the type of m_handle changed after the trick(i.e *(void **)(&m_handle)). Also is the size of function pointer the same as object pointer?

Comment: @BiaoCao No, the type of m_handle is not changed after the assignment. It will always remain a function pointer. And about the size, YES. Size of object pointers and function pointers are the same.

Comment: Or, to be more precise: if `dlsym` exists in a platform (natively or implemented by a third party), then a data-pointer has to be able to store a code-pointer,

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

The code should be:

```
void *m = dlsym(....);

m_handle = reinterpret_cast<decltype(m_handle)>(m);
```

The second line is *conditionally-supported* in C++ so we presume the code is being built by a compiler that does support converting `void *` to function pointer.

The original code causes undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation, it tries to pretend that `m_handle` is actually a `void *` object when it is not .

Being undefined behaviour, the original code may or may not appear to work the same as the correct version . It is certainly not a good idea to rely on undefined behaviour.

Comment: >>The original code causes undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation   ==>thanks for your reply, could you give more details or some reference about "strict aliasing violation"

Comment: @BiaoCao You can take a look at [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) .